# ksh alias or function that does "setTermName blah"

Tags: function, shell, ksh

I have the following line:

```
echo -ne "\033]0;blah\007"
```

that correctly sets the term name to `blah`. But if I place that line within a function, as in:

```
setTermName()
{
  echo -ne "\033]0;blah\007"
}
```

it doesn't work anymore. I guess escape sequences are not treated correctly within the function. So my question could be reformulated as: How do you use escape sequences within a function?

I only want to be able to do `setTermName foo` from command line.

Comment: What version of `ksh`? What OS?. What terminal? It works fine for me on Linux using ksh93, pdksh, Bash, zsh or dash in PuTTY, gnome-terminal, xterm or screen and on Cygwin using pdksh or Bash in mintty. What is your `PS1` set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoke that echo command from interactive ksh also? Are you sure it understands `-ne`? It's not standard. Maybe use `printf`.

And you can try to use `alias` instead.

UPD: I've checked with AIX ksh, the following function worked:

```
set_tn()
{
  printf "\033]0;$1\007"
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works if I print the echo from the command line of an interactive ksh. I have tried now with `printf "\b%s\a" $1` but it doesn't work either. Can you pass arguments to alias?

Comment: @rturrado What's your system/ksh? Probably i have some such system at hand to check. I've tried on AIX and there `echo` didn't understand -ne. Normally there's no problem with escapes in functions. How doesn't it work? It doesn't print anything, or just omits the escapes? Sorry for alias, i've lost that you need to pass an argument, so it's not an option here.

Comment: Hm... your set_tn() doesn't work for me. It just prints the argument on standard output. ksh --version shows: sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2010-02-02.

Comment: @rturrado: could be an issue with that particular ksh. What's your system anyway? Maybe i have something at hand to check. You can also check what's the value of TERM within the function.

Comment: Sorry man, I used your code in a function called title, and I had an alias called title as well, so I was always executing the alias. Your solution works ;-) BTW, $TERM=xterm when I printed it.

Comment: So finally — given that the environment is the same — echo doesn't work, but printf does? Weird, but today's the day of weird shell behaviour:) Anyway `printf` is now what should be used instead of `echo`.